# How to format the keyboard in order to have always "." dot instead of "," comma

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

I have textFields that contains latitude and longitude and I need to have always on decimal pad keyboard the dot"." instead of comma"," because if the region of user's iPhone is not USA or the for example Ukraine on the decimal pad keyboard I have the comma "," and my app is crashing. How to implement NumberFormatter to have always dot "."

Swift file to convert form textField text DMM coordinates to DM

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

func DMMtoDD(latDeg: Double, latMin: Double, latDir: String?, longDeg:    Double, longMin: Double, longDir: String?) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
var latitude = CLLocationDegrees()
if latDeg > 0 {
    latitude = CLLocationDegrees(latDeg + ((latMin*60)/3600))
    if latDir == "S" {latitude *= -1}
}
else{
    latitude = CLLocationDegrees((latDeg * -1) + ((latMin*60)/3600))
    latitude *= -1
}
var longitude = CLLocationDegrees()
if longDeg > 0 {
    longitude = CLLocationDegrees(longDeg + ((longMin*60)/3600))
    if longDir == "W" {longitude *= -1}
}
else{
    longitude = CLLocationDegrees((longDeg * -1) + ((longMin*60)/3600))
    longitude *= -1
}
return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

}
```

ViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let resultsVC = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
    let coord = DMMtoDD(latDeg: Double(latDegTextField.text!)!, latMin:      Double(latMinutesTextField.text!)!, latDir: String(latPTextField.text!),    longDeg: Double(longDegTextField.text!)!, longMin: Double(longMinutesTextField.text!)!, longDir: String(longPTextField.text!))
}
```

// How I'm using coordinates in my code

```
let G16 = (tghaSun + coord.longitude).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360.0)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the results?

Comment: The proper solution is to correctly deal with user's entering number using a , is many locales. Show your code causing the crash so we can help you fix it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are parsing the what the user has entered like this:

```
let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(whatTheUserEntered)
```

If the user's keyboard's locale was set to one that uses `,` as the decimal separator, `whatTheUserEntered` would contain something like `1,23`, and the above line would not parse the number correctly. Did I understand correctly?

Instead of trying to change the keyboard to show a `.`, change the way you parse the number to allow `,` to be used, depending on the user's locale.

Use a `NumberFormatter`:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
// numberFormatter takes the current locale into consideration by default
let longitude = numberFormatter.number(from: whatTheUserEntered).map { CLLocationDegrees($0) }
```

You can set `numberFormatter.locale` to `Locale(identifier: "uk")` (or another locale that uses `,` as the decimal separator) to test that this works:

```
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "uk")
```

Comment: FYI - the number formatter's locale defaults to the current locale. No need to set it explicitly.

Comment: Also note that `NumberFormatter number(from:)` returns an optional.

Comment: @rmaddy Didn't know that! Fixed.

Comment: @VladislavYarmak you are not using the solution in my answer.